# pg_dump and pg_restore across different major versions of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My development machine (call it D) runs PostgreSQL 9.4.5. My production machine (call it P) runs PostgreSQL 8.4.20.

I don't use any of the newer features or types in PostgreSQL 9.x.

Sometimes I need to mirror the state of P on D and sometimes I need to do the opposite. In both cases I use pg_dump/pg_restore.

I have never had any errors or warnings when I restore from a P dump to D. However, when I do the opposite I get multiple `unrecognized configuration parameter "lock_timeout"` errors. I know that this configuration parameter was introduced in 9.3 and as the rest of the restore process works fine, I just ignore the error messages.

**My questions are**: is it a bad idea to use pg_dump/pg_restore across different major versions or can one safely just ignore the compatibility errors as I have been doing here? Am I going to get bitten by this in the future? I cannot upgrade P, should I downgrade D to 8.4.20 just to be on the safe side?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> is it a bad idea to use pg_dump/pg_restore across different major versions

It's generally recommended that you use the `pg_dump` for the version you will be restoring to.

You should use a newer pg_dump when going from old version to new version.

Kind of annoying really.

> or can one safely just ignore the compatibility errors as I have been doing here?

It depends on what they are. You can ignore that one, yes.

> Am I going to get bitten by this in the future?

It depends on what you do. Obviously you can't ignore all errors - for example, if a `CREATE TABLE` fails you're in trouble. So it depends on the features used, etc.

> I cannot upgrade P, should I downgrade D to 8.4.20 just to be on the safe side?

Yes. Develop with the same version you run in production.

You need to upgrade P sooner or later though. Start planning. It's out of support, will get no further bugfixes, will not be packaged for new OS releases, and bug/problem reports will be met with "upgrade to a supported version and see if it still happens there".

Answer (score 18):

As PostgreSQL documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pgdump.html) says:

> Because pg_dump is used to transfer data to newer versions of PostgreSQL, the output of pg_dump can be expected to load into PostgreSQL server versions newer than pg_dump's version. pg_dump can also dump from PostgreSQL servers older than its own version. (Currently, servers back to version 8.0 are supported.) However, pg_dump cannot dump from PostgreSQL servers newer than its own major version; it will refuse to even try, rather than risk making an invalid dump. Also, it is not guaranteed that pg_dump's output can be loaded into a server of an older major version — not even if the dump was taken from a server of that version.

So, to others still having doubt about this, is not guaranteed that from a PgSQL server newer version, you have an 100% working output to an old version. But the opposite, will work just fine.

A recommendation, is to have your production server, if not the same as development, at least newer than it.

About ignoring compatibility errors:

> Loading a dump file into an older server may require manual editing of the dump file to remove syntax not understood by the older server. Use of the --quote-all-identifiers option is recommended in cross-version cases, as it can prevent problems arising from varying reserved-word lists in different PostgreSQL versions.

And a last recommendation, if you are planning a long life for your software, always consider upgrading, because the old versions will be deprecated some day. By the time that question was made, PgSQL 8 was still having releases. Now you only have releases from 9.6.

Answer (score 7):

For people coming across this question:  it is best to restore using the same version.
However, this is often not practical

Example: my local development machine is primarily Postgres 12.1 (port 5433) for development of next release.  I also have Postgres 11 installed (port 5432), since our production & CI are still on Postgres 11.

So I did the following:

- Create a test database in PG 12.1
- Manually applied appropriate migration scripts to the sample data used in CI
- exported using the PG 12 pg_dump to make a dump file

`"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump" -U postgres -p 5433 -d ut_20200621 --no-owner --no-acl "f:\dumps\ut_20200621_pg12.backup"`

- used the PG 12 pg_restore to load this into Postgres 11 (different port to server but same PG version)

`"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_restore" -U postgres -p 5432 -d ut_20200621 --no-owner --no-acl "f:\dumps\ut_20200621_pg12.backup"`

- Then create a dump on pg11:  Note use of the different version

`"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\pg_restore" -U postgres -p 5432 -d ut_20200621 --no-owner --no-acl "f:\dumps\ut_20200621_pg12.backup"`

Then my CI server can use the upgraded database that I created manually.

For release, the data migrations are run manually: first in staging, then in production.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Time and again I find myself at the mercy of a sysadmin for levelling off versions between two computers. So, if creating an older version test database on the original machine, this procedure by @sknutsonsf solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

The most important is to keep the workflow:

### Create a backup

**A.** To create a backup file using the `--format=custom` [`-Fc`] to restore it using `pg_restore`.

```hs
## for pg_restore
pg_dump -v -Fc \
postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<dbname> \
> db-20211122-163508.sql
```

**B.** If the version does not support `pg_restore` (PostgreSQL 9.0.23) remove `-Fc` and add `--clean` [`-c`] and restore using `psql`.

```hs
## for psql
pg_dump -v -c \
postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<dbname> \
> db-20211122-163508.sql
```

**Note:** Now, we add a connection string `postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>` and replace `<user>`, `<pass>`,`<host>`, `<port>`, and `<dbname>` with our real information.

### Restore

**A.** To restore the backup with `pg_restore`, we will execute it using `--clean` [`-c`] and `--create` [`-C`] to drop the database before restoring.

```hs
pg_restore -vcC \
-U <user> \
-h <host> \
-p <port> \
-d <dbname> \
< db-20211122-163508.sql
```

**B.** To restore with `psql` doesn't need any special option just remember to add the `--clean` [`-c`] to the `pg_dump`.

```hs
psql -v \
-U <user> \
-h <host> \
-p <port> \
-d <dbname> \
< db-20211122-163508.sql
```

**Note:** Now, replace `<user>`, `<host>`, `<port>`, and `<dbname>` with your information.

Answer (score 1):

My experience restore dump from 9.6 to 9.5.9
I use third server 9.5.13
copy file (initially create the backup)

replace the file on a server with  9.5.13

```
/usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

on server 9.5.13
`pg_restore  -U $POSTGRES_USER -h localhost  -d $POSTGRES_DB </tmp/dump.sql`
create dump
`pg_dump  -U $POSTGRES_USER -h localhost  -d $POSTGRES_DB -O -x > /tmp/dump_9_5_13.sql`

on server 9.5.9
`psql  -U $POSTGRES_USER -h localhost  -d $POSTGRES_DB </tmp/dump_9_5_13.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Date : 2022-11-22

I did the following to migrate data from PG11 to PG14.5

On PG11 host :

-modify pg_hba.conf to allow connection from PG14.5 host

-reload postgresql

From PG14.5 host :

-using pg_dump on pgsql14.5 to dump pgsql11 data and injecting data directly in pgsql14.5

```
bash $ psql
postgres# create database <dbname> with owner <user> ;
ctrl+d
bash $ psql -U <user> -d <dbname> < <(pg_dump -v -c postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<dbname> )
```

It has just work perfectly a couple of hours ago with a dotnet-core6 application which was not working when dumping it's old database on PG11 host with pgsql11 pg_dump command and when restoring on PG14.5 host with pgsql14.5 psql command.