# Postgres - Errors when restoring database from dump

Tags: postgresql, psql, restore, dump

I have a Postgres database dump of around 20GB size. I am trying to restore it using the command:

```sh
$ psql dbname < path-to-dump
```

which yields this final error:

[image]

After finding these questions ([2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287092/postgres-out-of-memory-error-while-importing-a-sql-file) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427689/psql-invalid-command-n-while-restore-sql/20428547)), I rerun the restoration process like so:

```sh
$ psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 dbname < path-to-dump
```

and got the first (out of many) error that occurs during the restoration:

[image]

This is the function where the specific error occurs:

```sql
--
-- Name: documents_search_trigger(); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: app
--

CREATE 
--

CREATE FUNCTION public.documents_search_trigger() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
          begin
            new.tsv := setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(new.name,'')), 'A');
            return new;
          end
      $$;
```

After researching, I found these answers ([[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64339344/error-syntax-error-at-or-near-function-while-db-restoring), [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826908/plpgsql-create-function-syntax-error-at-or-near-create)). I tried to encode the dump in UTF-8 using the command `iconv -f UTF-8 dump.sql > utf8dump.sql`, but again, nothing worked, as I am getting the same errors.

The postgres version of my ubuntu 20.04 machine is:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                             version                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.0 (Ubuntu 14.0-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

while the version of postgres where the dump was taken can be found in the dump itself:

```
$ head -15 dump.sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 12.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

I suspect there is a version mismatch problem, as I am getting more errors/warning before the `invalid command \N` starts taking over. Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Please show the complete error message with the offending statement, details etc.

Comment: Updated the question, the error message is the one shown: `ERROR: syntax error or at near "CREATE"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33600869/562459

Comment: I see. It would be interesting to see that line in the dump file, plus the stuff that comes immediately before it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added the lines before the function (which is the line where the first error occurs).

Comment: That single `CREATE` clearly is a syntax error. But `pg_dump` will never write a line like that. Investigate what was done to the file after it was created with `pg_dump`. Some misguided search/replace?

Comment: A version mismatch is not going to generate that stray "CREATE".  This file has been corrupted, almost certainly by something external (e.g. a well-meaning admin with a text editor)